# MarkerLight for Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Has anyone seen a something similar to MarkerLight ( http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples/source/browse/trunk/youtube/markerlight.js?r=2300 ) for API v3? That is, a lean custom marker overlay which loads really fast..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markers in v3 have been very heavily optimised - for example, in modern browsers the markers are rendered in `<canvas>` elements.

Have you measured using v3? Chances are you won't need something like MarkerLight at all.

Answer (score 0):

Pamela Fox, the author of `MarkerLight`, made these custom markers in V3:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/overlayview/custommarker.html?r=24